# tbl_summary not rendering in rmarkdown

Tags: gtsummary

I've experienced a new problem getting tables to display in a rmarkdown document. The tables don't display after knitting the rmarkdown to html either.  This is a new problem which started about 2 weeks ago. I previously had no problem with this and previous documents do run and display tables correctly. I haven't updated R Studio recently (using version 4.0.5), I use the same set up code as for previous rmd documents. The only way I can get the table to display in an rmd document is to run it two times, the first time it doesn't display but if I highlight it and run it again it will display. Any recommendations?

Comment: If you post a reproducible example, we can assist. Without one, there is not much we can do.  Please check out how to create a reprex

Comment: I managed to resolve the problem by removing 'include = FALSE' from one rmd code chunk. Thank you for the work you've put into gtsummary. I've been really pleased with the reports I can generate from the package.